# How to store configuration in constants easy?

Tags: java, properties, configuration, refactoring, constants

For some time I was working on the project, where all configuration was stored in constants of the `Config` class. I found this very comfortable: to use any property all that I need to write is `Config.PROPERTY_NAME`. Fast, simple, understandable. Much more comfortable than `CONFIG.getString("StringNameWithoutAutocompletion", defaultValue)`.

But where it comes to add new configuration constant, there is some troubles: I need to copy-paste and then change existing constant in the `Config` class (twice in my project), and then try not forget add it in the .properties file. Also, if later I want to change property name, I need specify it in both places.

So, there is a question: it is possible to get clean `Config.NAME` properties without changing the `Config` class manually every time?

One of possible (but not really good for me) solutions that I can imagine is by using .java files instead of .properties, and compile them on program load.

I think the easiest way is to generate constants inside `Config` class automatically from the properties file, so if I add `MyProperty` in the .properties file, it will instantly become available as `MY_PROPERTY` constant. May be there is some library with power similar to [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a constant defined on a class (Config in this case) you have to edit the class to add it.

If you really don't want to repeat yourself you could generate the constants class from the properties file, but that does mean you would have to regenerate the class every time you edited the properties file. Pick your poison.

Comment: As I read from other Stackoverflow's question, constants is a proper way to store Properties. It's hard to believe that no one made a solution to accomplish that easy. If you know how to _regenerate the class every time you edited the properties file_ please tell me, and maybe I'll be able to automate this process in my projects. I think I should check plugins for my IDE, perhaps the answer will be there...